# Compare cell against series of cell pairs

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to make a LibreOffice spreadsheet formula that populates a column based on another input column, comparing each input with a series of range pairs defined in another sheet and finally outputting a symbol based on matched criteria. I have a series of ranges that specify a `-` output, and another series that corresponds to `+`, but not all inputs will fall into a category. I am using this trinary output later for another expression, which I already have in place.

My question becomes: how can I test input against each range pair without spelling out the cell coordinates for each individual cell (ie `OR(AND(">= $A$1", "< $B$1"), AND(">=$A$2", "<$B$2"), ...)`)? Ideally I could just specify an array to compare against like `$A$1:$B$4`. Writing it in a python macro would work, too, since I don't plan on sharing this file.

I wrote a really quick list comp in python to illustrate what I'm after. This snippet would be one half, such as testing `-` qualification, and these values may be fed into a condition that outputs the symbol:

```
>>> def cmp(f, r):
...     return r[0] <= f < r[1]
>>> f = (1, 2, 3)
>>> ranges = ((2, 5), (4, 6), (3, 8))
>>> [any([cmp(i, r) for r in ranges]) for i in f]
[False, True, True]
```

Here is a small [test example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jDFhFL1MkVOuu2Nu695EifPyA_dUGEYhMXURNp-AjDU) with real input and real ranges.

Comment: Can input values like `145.7000` occur?  If not, then the formula in my answer could be simplified to only one `VLOOKUP` instead of two.

Comment: Yes, 145.7 would be acceptable input. This is a list of frequencies in the 2-meter amateur radio band, so anything between 144.0-148.0 is valid input. I'll be taking a closer look when I get home tonight. Thanks for linking documentation, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the range pairs so that they are in two columns starting from A13.  Be sure that they are in sorted order (*Data -> Sort*).

```
A           B           C
~~~~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~    ~
145.1000    145.5000    -
146.0000    146.4000    +
146.6000    147.0000    -
147.0000    147.4000    +
147.6000    148.0000    -
440.0000    445.0000    +
```

In each row, specify whether it is negative or positive.  To do this, I entered the following formula in C13 and filled down.  If the range pairs are not consistent enough then enter values for C13 and below manually.

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW());"-";"+")
```

Now, enter the following formula in cell C3 and fill down.

```
=IFNA(IF(
    VLOOKUP(A3;A$13:C$18;2;1) >= A3;
    VLOOKUP(A3;A$13:C$18;3;1);
    "None");"None")
```

The formula finds the closest pair and then checks if the number is inside that range or not.  For better testing, I would also suggest using `145.7000` as input, which should result in no shift if I understood the question correctly.

The results in column C:

```
-
+
None
None
```

Documentation: [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP), [IFNA](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#IFNA), [ROW](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ROW).

**EDIT**:

The following formula produces correct results for the example data you gave, and it works for anything between 144.0 and 148.0.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3;A$13:C$18;3;1); "None")
```

However, 150.0 produces `-` and 550.0 produces `+`.  If that is not what you want, then use the formula above that has two `VLOOKUP` expressions.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Now it's telling me that my expression to determine shift amount is wrong, which I will rework to behave like this. I kept seeing `VLOOKUP` in many other answers, but I never really understood it. Essentially it's two pairs of columns called: first finds the upper limit from the lower, then it finds the shift direction from the lower limit.

Comment: Also I've been able to adapt this to my real document that has ranges and other hidden data on a separate sheet, so I'm learning a whole lot about spreadsheet notation here.